# HSM AES Key Extraction

Tags: java, export, pkcs#11, hsm

I have a Thales nShield HSM in which I have created a (CKA_SENSATIVE, false) AES key that I want to extract but, I can not figure out how to do it in java at all. My Key creation looks just like this:

```
CK_ATTRIBUTE[] aesKeyObject = new CK_ATTRIBUTE[14];

    try
    {
        aesKeyObject[0] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA_CLASS, CKO_SECRET_KEY);
        aesKeyObject[1] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA_KEY_TYPE, CKK_AES);
        aesKeyObject[2] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA_VALUE_LEN, 32);
        aesKeyObject[3] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA_TOKEN, true);
        aesKeyObject[4] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA_LABEL, "TestAES".getBytes());
        aesKeyObject[5] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA_PRIVATE, true);
        aesKeyObject[6] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA_EXTRACTABLE, true);
        aesKeyObject[7] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA_WRAP, true);
        aesKeyObject[8] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA_UNWRAP, true);
        aesKeyObject[9] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA_ENCRYPT, true);
        aesKeyObject[10] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA_DECRYPT, true);
        aesKeyObject[11] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA_TRUSTED, true);
        aesKeyObject[12] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA_ID, 1550);
        aesKeyObject[13] = new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA_SENSITIVE, false);

        CK_MECHANISM mech = new CK_MECHANISM(CKM_AES_KEY_GEN);

        long newAESKeyHandle = p11.C_GenerateKey(hSession, mech, aesKeyObject);     
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
```

Comment: @zaph it is the nShield

Answer (score 0):

You need to read `CKA_VALUE` attribute of generated key object with `C_GetAttributeValue` function.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that answer in a previous post. Can you be a little more specific? I have done: 
p11.C_GetAttributeValue(hSession, newAESKeyHandle, CKA_VALUE); to which i gives me a value of 1126. Not really sure what that is.

I have also done:
CK_ATTRIBUTE[] KeyValue = new CK_ATTRIBUTE[] {
new CK_ATTRIBUTE(CKA_VALUE, newAESKeyHandle)
};